# Java Incorrect KeyEventDispatcher Being Referenced

Tags: java, swing

> (Disclaimer: I'm relatively new to Swing)

In a GUI, I've created two objects of the same type (`JButton`). Each have their own `KeyEventDispatcher` and post their `KeyEvents` to separate `EventQueues`. When initializing and adding the two objects to two separate `JPanel`, the first button object created works properly and will send the correct data upon pressing the button. However, the second button object is unresponsive. This behavior is consistent, regardless of the order which I initialize and add them.

Upon further debugging and analyzing where these two `KeyEventDispatcher` events in the virtual memory, I found that upon pressing the second button, the `KeyEventDispatcher` of the first button created is being referenced by the `overrode dispatchKeyEvent` method. From what I can tell, this seems to be the cause of why the second button created is unresponsive.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: `I've created two objects of the same JButton-type class which each have their own KeyEventDispatcher and post their KeyEvents to separate EventQueues` - why? `I'm relatively new to Swing` - I'm guessing you don't understand how Swing works. Start by reading the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics.

Comment: did you copy and paste the second one and are actually still referencing the previous one in the second ones code?

Comment: There's almost never a reason to use a `KeyEventDispatcher`, especially since you're using buttons. You probably just need to use `ActionListener`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html. `KeyEventDispatcher` is for when you're trying to do something non-standard. (Edit: and on the off-chance you actually did need to use `KeyEventDispatcher`, you need to read the focus specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/FocusSpec.html.)

Comment: If you're still having trouble please post your code ([SSCCE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiPwdeSuv_UAhUKQCYKHYSnCd0QFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsscce.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNFdqWH-Hxu7Vlsk6vBvl9vWtnAdrw)).